# Screenshots take forever to appear in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, screen-capture

Fresh install of macOS Catalina 10.15.2

In screenshot's options I turned off that "show floating thumbnail" thing and set the screenshot folder to `~/Downloads`.

Sometimes I take a screenshot and it takes upwards of 10 seconds to appear in Finder.

This is with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> screenshots (draw a rectangle ones), I haven't tested others.

Behaviour seems random.

How do I make the screenshots consistently appear within at most half a second?

Comment: Screenshots can be slow depending on the resolution and number of displays involved, snipping sections of the display is usually quicker but still more than half a second in my experience.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374985/screenshots-take-so-long-to-appear-in-folder You could put a bounty on the older one too :)